# Use JAXB to parse a XML file as a stream

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a XML file which contains a lot of employees record (say up to 1M)  as follows:

```
<employee>
 <name>peter</name>
 <mobile>435432</mobile>
<employee>
<employee>
 <name>Mary</name>
 <mobile>324213</mobile>
<employee>
<employee>
 <name>May</name>
 <mobile>54342423</mobile>
<employee>
```

I map an employee record using JAXB to the following Java object:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;
}
```

The content of the XML cannot be changed and given this XML , how can I use JAXB to unmarshal each employee XML record to Employee object such that I can process it one by one?

Comment: Does your XML have a root element?

Comment: My XML does not have a root element

Comment: See the update to my answer on how to handle the missing root element:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29846685/383861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the XML with a StAX `XMLStreamReader` then navigate to the first `emoloyee` element and unmarshal the `XMLStreamReader` at that state, then position it at the next `emoloyee` element and repeat.

### UPDATE

> My XML does not have a root element

You should be able to leverage a `SequenceInputStream` for your use case.  You will create in on 3 instances of `InputStream`:

1. One representing a start element you make up
2. The second representing the content shown in your question
3. The last representing the close element to the element you opened in the first `InputStream`.

Then pass the instance of `SequenceInputStream` to the `XMLStreamReader` I mentioned in my original answer and you should be good.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html